# Data Gridview in c#

Tags: c#, datagrid

I am new to C# programming I am able to fetch data in a text box through serial port. Data is coming like this:

```
------------------------------JL206F             ID:VDE40050

2015/05/29    11:02:19      

JBatch_No.:067

JOperator ID:15

--------------------------------

        Mixed Counting

W--------------------------------Deposit Amount:             0.00

--------------------------------

denom       count          value

UVK(|????DW50D        1          50.00

JUVK(|????DW20D       1          20.00

JUVK(|????DW10ND          1          10.00

J--------------------------------

Total:          3          80.00

--------------------------------

Coin:                       0.00

--------------------------------

Balance:                    0.00
```

I want this data to be in data grid categorised as time balance etc. May I know how can I do it.

Comment: This question is currently too broad. Show what you have tried then we might be able to improve or fix your code.

Comment: my question is just that How can I put the data that is coming in my textbox to datagridview.

Comment: You can add these data to a datatable, and then set gridView.dataSource=datatable.

But you should specify your columns first.

Comment: int maxTextLength = 1000; // maximum text length in text box
            if (tbData.TextLength > maxTextLength)
                tbData.Text = tbData.Text.Remove(0, tbData.TextLength - maxTextLength);
            string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Data);
           
            tbData.ScrollToCaret();
            string[] Text = tbData.Text.Split(',');
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Column1, Column2, Column3);
            tbData.AppendText(str);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(str);


        }

Comment: This is my code and it is putting data in first column only and seperating the data with each and every bit.